# What do the different symbols in the API section of the XCode Documentation mean?

Tags: xcode, documentation

Looking at the API section on the left side of the XCode Documentation, I've always wondered what the symbols mean?

For instance, there's a "K" in a green square, a "T" in an orange square, an "M" in a blue square, etc.

Is there a key for these?

Thanks!

Rashiki

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- C: Class, like `NSString`
- M: Method, like `-initWithString:`
- ## : Define, like `nil`
- f: Function, like `CFStringAppend()`
- T: Typedef, usually enums like `NSStringEncoding`
- K: Constants, usually a member of an enum like `NSUTF8StringEncoding`
- G: Global instances, usually strings like `NSDirectoryFileType`

Comment: Great!  Thanks!  I think I'm a long way off from knowing what each of these means, but at least the key is there now.  ;-)  Ha, ha.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to expand the list for XCode circa late 2011:

C: Class
M: Method
#: Define
f: Function
T: Typedef 
K: Constants
G: Global instance
V: Keys for a dictionary and KVO/KVC 
E: Enumeration
P: Property 
(books,papers): Library 
(a book): Category or conceptual document 
(XCode icon): Sample code project
(sheet of paper): Document page or section
?: Help article